# Touch ID API - using just the PIN for non-touch ID phones?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, touch-id

Been searching around for this, but can't seem to find an appropriate answer. Currently I have a system in my app in place to opt for a PIN to enter the app. I'd like to incorporate Touch ID instead, but can't figure out what to do for non-Touch ID phones.

Question: Can we use the Touch ID API to request the user enter their phone PIN to enter the app for those who do not have the Touch ID hardware?

Comment: Apps have no access to the device-level passcode entry. If you want to protect your app with a passcode for devices with no touch id or device that haven't been setup to use touch id, then you need to implement your own passcode screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is to to test if we can evaluate the policy, this test will tell us if Touch ID is available and enrolled. If `NO` you can use your own PIN view for authorization.

```
LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];
NSError *error;
BOOL test = [context canEvaluatePolicy: LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&error];
if (test) {
    [context evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics localizedReason:@"For some reasons" reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (success) {
            // authorized successfully
        }
    }];
} else {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
    // use a pin code
}
```

As I have tried, you can't access to the built-in PIN and need to use a custom view instead.